# Sql to select Max event on two grouped by one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table :

```
+----------+------+
| country  | event     |
+----------+-----------+
|   usa    | running   |
|   usa    | running   |
|   usa    | running   |
|  canada  | running   |
|  Canada  | running   |
|   usa    |  javline  |
|  canada  |  javline  |
|  canada  |  javline  |
|  canada  |  javline  |
+----------+-----------+
```

I want to get the following out by sql query:

```
USA    |  Running |  3
Canada |  Javline |  3
```

i tried using the following query on MS sql server :

```
select country, case when c > 1 then null else event end event 
  from (select country, [ModelName], recs, count(*) over (partition by event, recs ) c, 
           row_number() over (partition by country order by recs desc) rn
  from (select country, event, count(*) recs
          from table
         group by country, event)  )
 where rn = 1
 order by 1
```

But I get an error  :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Any pointers to correct solution is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put an alias on your subquery:

```
select 
    country, 
    case when c > 1 then null else event end event 
from (
    select  -- No event here
        country, 
        [ModelName], 
        recs, 
        count(*) over (partition by event, recs ) c, 
        row_number() over (partition by country order by recs desc) rn
    from (
        select country, event, count(*) recs -- No ModelName here
        from [table]
        group by country, event
    ) x -- You need to put an alias here
)t -- and here
 where rn = 1
 order by 1
```

*Note that the above query will still produce errors:*

> Invalid column name 'ModelName'.
>
> Invalid column name 'event'.

This is because `ModelName` is not included in your innermost subquery and `event` is not included in the outermost subquery.

---

Based on your sample data, you can use this query to achieve the desired result:

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT Country, Event, COUNT(*) AS CC
    FROM [Table]
    GROUP BY Country, Event
)
,CteRowNumber AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY CC DESC)
    FROM Cte
)
SELECT Country, Event, CC
FROM CteRowNumber
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot   i added the missing aliases and it worked perfectly !! .

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using window function inside a cte:

```
-- this counts a number per each country and event
with q as(
  select country,event,
  row_number() over(partition by country,event order by country) r
  from your_table t
  )
--this takes only the maximum of them
select * 
from q
where r=(select max(r) 
          from q q2 
          where q2.country=q.country)
```

*Result:*

```
    | country |   event | r |
    |---------|---------|---|
    |  canada | javline | 3 |
    |     usa | running | 3 |
```

Comment: This Solution Also works . just need to see the difference in performance . Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome, and also I don't think it has performance issue, anyway. good luck bro.